# Recoger dos variables para eliminar y editar

Tags: php, pdo, grocery-crud

Me sigue devolviendo error pongo los 3 documentos que utilizo. Los problemas me vienen de los  que tengo al final creo

index.php

```
// Logica
$alm = new Categoria();
$model = new CategoriaModel();

if (isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {
    case 'actualizar':



        // Recupero el id del campo hidden

        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $_REQUEST['acro_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $_REQUEST['acro_subcategoria']);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $_REQUEST['tipo_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $_REQUEST['registro_calidad']);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $_REQUEST['calidad_code']);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $_REQUEST['cod_tempo']);

        $update_results = $model->Actualizar($alm, $_POST['id']);

        header('Location: index2.php');

        break;

    case 'registrar':
        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $_REQUEST['acro_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $_REQUEST['acro_subcategoria']);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $_REQUEST['tipo_documento']);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $_REQUEST['registro_calidad']);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $_REQUEST['calidad_code']);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $_REQUEST['cod_tempo']);

        $model->Registrar($alm);
        header('Location: index2.php');
        break;

    case 'eliminar':
        $model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['acro_documento']);
        $model->Eliminar($_REQUEST['acro_subcategoria']);
        header('Location: index2.php');
        break;

    case 'editar':
        // Recupero los datos por el id
        // $obj_categoria es un objeto del tipo Categoria
        $obj_categoria = $model->Obtener($_REQUEST['id']);

        break;
    default:
        // MENSAJE 404 PARA CUANDO LA ACCION NO ES VALIDA
        header('HTTP/1.0: 404 Not Found');
        die('<h1>404 Page Not Found</h1>');
}
}
?>
```

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">
</head>
<body style="padding:15px;">

    <div class="pure-g">
        <div class="pure-u-1-12">

            <form action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_documento'): ''; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_subcategoria'): ''; ?>" />

                <table style="width:500px;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Documento</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="acro_documento"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Subcategoria</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="acro_subcategoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('acro_subcategoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Tipo de Documento</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="tipo_documento"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('tipo_documento') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Registro de Calidad</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="registro_calidad"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('registro_calidad') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Calidad Code</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="calidad_code"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('calidad_code') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo de Tiempo</th>
                        <td><input type="text" name="cod_tempo"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('cod_tempo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

            <table class="pure-table pure-table-horizontal">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Documento</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo Subcategoria</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Tipo de Documento</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Registro de Calidad</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Calidad Code</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Codigo de tiempo</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Edicion</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">Eliminar</th>


                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php foreach ($model->Listar() as $r): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('acro_documento'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('acro_subcategoria'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('tipo_documento'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('registro_calidad'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('calidad_code'); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->__GET('cod_tempo'); ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo $r->acro_documento;?>"
                               href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>"
                            >
                            <img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="?action=eliminar&acro_documento=<?php echo $r->acro_documento; ?>"
                               href="?action=eliminar&acro_subcategoria=<?php echo $r->acro_subcategoria; ?>"
                            >
                            <img src="delete.png" width="30px" height=30px"/></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

alumno.model2.php

```
<?php

class CategoriaModel {

private $pdo;

public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=deimos1', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Listar() {
    try {
        $result = array();

        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipodocumentos");
        $stm->execute();

        foreach ($stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $r) {
            $alm = new Categoria();

            $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $r->acro_documento);
            $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $r->acro_subcategoria);
            $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $r->tipo_documento);
            $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $r->registro_calidad);
            $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $r->calidad_code);
            $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $r->cod_tempo);
            $result[] = $alm;
        }

        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Obtener($acronimo) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento  = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
        $r = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        $alm = new Categoria();

        $alm->__SET('acro_documento', $r->acro_documento);
        $alm->__SET('acro_subcategoria', $r->acro_subcategoria);
        $alm->__SET('tipo_documento', $r->tipo_documento);
        $alm->__SET('registro_calidad', $r->registro_calidad);
        $alm->__SET('calidad_code', $r->calidad_code);
        $alm->__SET('cod_tempo', $r->cod_tempo);

        return $alm;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function Eliminar($acronimo) {
    try {
        $stm = $this->pdo
                ->prepare("DELETE FROM tipodocumentos WHERE acro_documento = ? and acro_subcategoria = ?");

        $stm->execute(array($acronimo));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// ##############################################################################################
// CAMBIOS REALIZADOS
// - USO DE PARAMETROS NOMBRADOS EN EN METODO .execute()
// ##############################################################################################       
public function Actualizar(Categoria $data, $acro_doc_viejo, $acro_sub_viejo) {

    try {

        $sql = "UPDATE tipodocumentos SET tipo_documento =:tipo_documento, registro_calidad =:registro_calidad, calidad_code =:calidad_code, "
                . "cod_tempo =:cod_tempo, acro_documento =:acro_documento, acro_subcategoria =:acro_subcategoria WHERE acro_documento=:acro_doc_viejo and acro_subcategoria =:acro_sub_viejo";



        return $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
                        ->execute(
                                array(
                                    ':acro_doc_viejo' => $acro_doc_viejo,
                                    ':acro_sub_viejo' => $acro_sub_viejo,
                                    ':acro_documento' => $data->__GET('acro_documento'),
                                    ':acro_subcategoria' => $data->__GET('acro_subcategoria'),
                                    ':tipo_documento' => $data->__GET('tipo_documento'),
                                    ':registro_calidad' => $data->__GET('registro_calidad'),
                                    ':calidad_code' => $data->__GET('calidad_code'),
                                    ':cod_tempo' => $data->__GET('cod_tempo')
                                )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// ##############################################################################################

public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tipodocumentos (acro_documento,acro_subcategoria,tipo_documento,registro_calidad,calidad_code,cod_tempo)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)
                ->execute(
                        array(
                            $data->__GET('acro_documento'),
                            $data->__GET('acro_subcategoria'),
                            $data->__GET('tipo_documento'),
                            $data->__GET('registro_calidad'),
                            $data->__GET('calidad_code'),
                            $data->__GET('cod_tempo')
                        )
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

alumno.entidad2.php

```
<?php
class Categoria
{
private $acro_documento;
private $acro_subcategoria;
    private $tipo_documento;
    private $registro_calidad;
    private $calidad_code;
    private $cod_tempo;

public function __GET($k){ return $this->$k; }
public function __SET($k, $v){ return $this->$k = $v; }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir los código de tus modelos? Da la impresión de que estás preparando una sentencia SQL con más o menos parámetros de los que estás pasando.

Comment: Ya esta editado todo el contenido de nuevo con los 3 archivos que utilizo